# Remove duplicates from a column whose values are separated by a pipe

Tags: sql, string, csv, google-bigquery

The data looks like below-

```
category_id   category_name    associated_keys
    111          Books         CC34DE5W|SQA7ZZ87|LM24NO3P|SQA7ZZ87
    222          Office        LM24NO3P|AAB12B34
    444         Furniture      X34YY78Z|LM24NO3P|SQA7ZZ87|SEF5C6T4|CC34DE5W|AAB12B34
    222          Office        X34YY78Z|X34YY78Z
```

I want to remove duplicates from the associated_keys column for a distinct category_id. The output should look like below-

```
category_id   category_name    associated_keys
    111          Books         CC34DE5W|SQA7ZZ87|LM24NO3P
    222          Office        LM24NO3P|AAB12B34
    444         Furniture      X34YY78Z|LM24NO3P|SQA7ZZ87|SEF5C6T4|CC34DE5W|AAB12B34
    222          Office        X34YY78Z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT category_id, category_name, 
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT key, '|') FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(associated_keys, '|')) key) associated_keys
FROM (
  SELECT category_id, category_name, STRING_AGG(associated_keys, '|') AS associated_keys
  FROM `project.dataset.data` 
  GROUP BY category_id, category_name  
)
```

If to apply to sample data from your example  - output is

```
Row category_id category_name   associated_keys  
1   111         Books           CC34DE5W|SQA7ZZ87|LM24NO3P   
2   222         Office          LM24NO3P|AAB12B34|X34YY78Z   
3   444         Furniture       X34YY78Z|LM24NO3P|SQA7ZZ87|SEF5C6T4|CC34DE5W|AAB12B34
```

In case if you don't want to group by category_id (as in last questions) - use below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT category_id, category_name, 
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT key, '|') FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(associated_keys, '|')) key) associated_keys
FROM `project.dataset.data`
```

with output

```
Row category_id category_name   associated_keys  
1   111         Books           CC34DE5W|SQA7ZZ87|LM24NO3P   
2   222         Office          LM24NO3P|AAB12B34    
3   444         Furniture       X34YY78Z|LM24NO3P|SQA7ZZ87|SEF5C6T4|CC34DE5W|AAB12B34    
4   222         Office          X34YY78Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't store such values as strings!  BigQuery offers arrays.  So, I'll show you how to transform the result from the string into an array:

```
with t as (
      select 111 as category_id, 'Books' as category_name, 'CC34DE5W|SQA7ZZ87|LM24NO3P|SQA7ZZ87' as associated_keys union all
      select 222, 'Office', 'LM24NO3P|AAB12B34' union all
      select 444, 'Furniture', 'X34YY78Z|LM24NO3P|SQA7ZZ87|SEF5C6T4|CC34DE5W|AAB12B34' union all
      select 222, 'Office', 'X34YY78Z|X34YY78Z'
     )
select t.* except (associated_keys),
       (select array_agg(distinct key)
        from unnest(split(t.associated_keys, '|')) key
       ) as associated_keys
from t;
```

You can use `string_agg()` if you really want to reconstruct a string, but I don't recommend that.